# INSERT Trigger for a rating system: Division by zero error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have followed [this paper](https://onextrapixel.com/how-to-build-a-5-star-rating-system-with-wilson-interval-in-mysql/) which suggests what is claimed to be a good approach to 5 star rating systems.

The schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `positive` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `negative` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `stars` float DEFAULT 0,
  `total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lower_bound` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I setup the INSERT trigger which is:

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER `insert_rating` BEFORE INSERT ON `ratings`
    FOR EACH ROW
           SET new.total = new.positive + new.negative,
     new.stars = ROUND( (((new.positive / new.total) * 4) + 1) * 2, 0) / 2,
     new.lower_bound = ((new.positive + 1.9208) / (new.positive + new.negative) - 1.96 * SQRT((new.positive * new.negative) / (new.positive + new.negative) + 0.9604) / (new.positive + new.negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (new.positive + new.negative))
```

but upon my first insert of (Also taken from the paper):

```
INSERT into ratings (product_id, positive, negative) VALUES (1, 0, 0)
```

I got a Division by zero error. Is there an SQL error in the design of this method or have I done something wrong? Would like to know how to fix.

There's also an update trigger but I don't think I will ever need to update it with zeros:

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER `update_rating` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ratings`
    FOR EACH ROW
      SET new.total = new.positive + new.negative,
      new.stars = ROUND( (((new.positive / new.total) * 4) + 1) * 2, 0) / 2,
      new.lower_bound = ((new.positive + 1.9208) / (new.positive + new.negative) - 1.96 * SQRT((new.positive * new.negative) / (new.positive + new.negative) + 0.9604) / (new.positive + new.negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (new.positive + new.negative))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's answer will prevent the error.

The trigger expects either positive or negative to be non-zero, which makes sense. Your insert statement adds NO actual ratings (either positive or negative); so what's the point?

More importantly, why not save yourself some headaches and change the columns to do the work for you?

In your table definition, change the columns to

```
...
total INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (positive+negative) STORED,
stars INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ROUND((((positive/NULLIF(positive+negative,0))*4)+1) *2, 0)/2) STORED,
lower_bound DOUBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((positive + 1.9208) / NULLIF(positive + negative, 0) - 1.96 * SQRT((positive * negative) / (positive + negative) + 0.9604) / NULLIF(positive + negative, 0))) / (1 + 3.8416 / NULLIF(positive + negative, 0)) STORED,
...
```

(And remove all the triggers, of course)

Comment: The insert is presumably just to get the product in the ratings table so it is ratable by a future `UPDATE`.

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with `GENERATED` and `STORED` but I will check them. Thx

Comment: Note that the formulas are straight copies from Gordon's answer -- any fix there should be applied here as well, of course.

Comment: Can't I just get rid of the insert trigger and rely solely on the update trigger? Then, rather than insert a row upon the first rating for a product, I insert a row when the product itself is created, setting its values to zero. When someone submits a rating, I run the update? Will this negatively affect the Wilson score system in any way?

Comment: Yes, but please please consider calculated columns instead. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Of course. This solution is the one I will implement before production after I research a bit about them. Dev cycle deadlines come first, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It is like really hard to tell *which* division is causing the issue.  But the solution is `NULLIF()`:

```
       SET new.total = new.positive + new.negative,
           new.stars = ROUND( (((new.positive / NULLIF(new.total, 0)) * 4) + 1) * 2, 0) / 2,
 n         new.lower_bound = ((new.positive + 1.9208) / NULLIF(new.positive + new.negative, 0) - 1.96 * SQRT((new.positive * new.negative) / NULLIF(new.positive + new.negative, 0) + 0.9604) / NULLIF(new.positive + new.negative, 0))) / (1 + 3.8416 / NULLIF(new.positive + new.negative, 0)
```

This turns `0`s into `NULL`s, so the result is `NULL` rather than an error.

Comment: I think you have an extra closing paren on the second-to-last `NULLIF`

Comment: hmm. I updated the trigger but got the same Division by 0 error upon insert.

Comment: @xendi . . . You need to do this for all the expressions.  I find that logic rather hard to follow, but you are more familiar with it so it will be easier to determine where the denominators are.

Answer (score 0):

The following line sets new.total to 0

```
SET new.total = new.positive + new.negative
```

The next line has new.positive / new.total. Since you just set new.total to 0 you get a divide by 0. I would try testing for this condition and setting new.stars = 0 where is happens.